# How can I run my Python code on other system which doesn't have the required external library module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have built a Python application using an external library (lxml-module). This runs fine in my system. Is there any way to compile this code or package this code, so that I can run it in another system which does not have this external library (lxml-module) module installed in it?

If possible please give me a little reference on *.pyd also?

Comment: Read about eggs, and how dependencies are described.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you cant simply install `lmxl` to `PYTHONPATH` on the target system?

Answer (score 1):

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org)  would be a good way to go to package your code.

It works in a configure/make/build workflow (before which you setup a small spec file with different kinds of options). The external package will be shipped along with your application.

lxml is supported in PyInstaller: http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/SupportedPackages.

As for being able to compile your code on another machine, [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21640/marcin) had a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows package up using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), for OSX use [py2app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) and for Linux possibly use [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I don't think OP wants to bundle all of Python with the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can always copy the module to your local path and import it from there. Kind of what django did for `json` until it was included in the standard library.

This could do the trick:

```
try:
    import lxml
except ImportError:
    import myownmodules.lxml as lxml
```

I know this is the less "high tech" approach but if the problem is simple enough this is what I would do without a blink.

Besides .... our buddy Tim seems to agree: "If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea."